# Implement search on FutureBuilder data

Tags: flutter, dart, search, async-await, future

I have implemented FutureBuilder to populate a ListView. Now I want to implement search functionality on this populated ListView.
Here is code how I did this:

```
FutureBuilder<ChatGroupListModel>(
      future: localChatGroupList,
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.listChatGroupListModel.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ChatTileWidget(
                  chatGroupModel: snapshot.data.listChatGroupListModel[index],
                );
              },
            );
          }else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }else return Center(
            child: NoDataWidget(),
          );
        } else return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicatorWidget()
        );
      },
    );
```

Now I want to search on this populated data. Please share how I can do this without recalling API.

Comment: so you need a `StreamBuilder` (instead of `FutureBuilder`) returning a new `snapshot` each time you type a "search" `TextField`

Comment: @pskink so you mean every time I have to call API. I don't want to call API on every character change.

Comment: no, it does not mean that you have to call API - you can call it once and use `List.where` for filtering

Comment: @pskink please suggest how I can achieve.

Comment: text field part: `child: TextField(onChanged: streamController.add)` and now you need to implement search stream, like: `streamController.stream.debounce(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).asyncMap((query) => call list.where() based on input query text)`